# sharepoint datawebpart paging issue with groupings

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, dataviewwebpart

I created a dataview webpart in designer and have two different groupings.  I enabled the grouping headers so they show up in my webpart.  The issue I am having is that I want to make the first grouping visible on the first page (or other pages) so people then use the expand/collapse functionality to view other info.  When I select display all items option in the paging functionality, the webpart breaks.  Please help.